# iphone developer program 99USD per year?

Tags: iphone-developer-program

apple charge the iphone developer program 99 USD per year or one time payment?

Answer (score 5):

It's per year.

Comment: But the unknown is, what happens to your app if you decide not to renew?  I suspect that it will remain for sale, but who really knows?

Comment: Why is it awful?  I'm used to spending money on good development environments when they're closed-source.  I also waste a whole lot more than $99/year on a whole lot of things, so if I actually got busy on iPhone development I'd think it cheap.

Comment: I see your point David. Its just my personal opinion, I guess its (one of) apple's ways to make money.

Comment: $99/year is less than 30 cents a day. A developer that can't afford that needs a career change.

Comment: Terry, yes!  Apple is providing a lot of service for this $99, am I right?  Don't sign up until you are ready to publish an app, if you object to this cost.

Comment: The dev tools for other phones I've developed for like the Blackberry, Nokia, and Palm have all been free.  And you aren't forced to have your apps approved by the iStore to sell them.  I see the $99 as paying for access to the iPhone app market, not for the dev tools.  And even though $99 isn't much, it could go to a much better cause.  Like the shareware utility you use every day, but never registered, or that website you read every day but never dontate to.  IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

It's an annual fee.

Quote: "*The Standard Program costs $99 (US) per year and gives members an iPhone SDK and development tools; access to pre-release iPhone software; technical support*"

[Link to the press release mentioning it](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2008/03/06iphone.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can distribute for free through Cydia.